# LiPo Battery charging time with TP4056

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charger, tp4056

I recycled some old ASUS battery laptop, with notes it had 15 V and 66 Wh rating. Then I disassembled it. Found 4 LiPo cells connected in series, each may be rated 3.88 V from a small print on each cell. Then I got my TP4056 charger and tried to charge it. Noticed it was charging and the voltage went up to 3.84 V but noticed the RED led never went to BLUE and it was already charging for 6-7 h.
Is it normal for it to take that long or am I doing something wrong like the charger module is incompatible? Did some few searches and they said it should be fine using the TP4056 for LiPo battery.

Im also planning to parallel 2 cells and charge them using 1 TP4056, is it possible or safe?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Welcome! If the battery was still connected to the BMS and you charged only one cell, probably balancing kicked in and tried its best to resistivley burn off charge until the cells were equal voltage again. Best case (never seen in a laptop pack), inductive BMS and it tried to charge all other cells, taking really long time. But please draw a schematic of how you connected things. If you parallel two cells not having well matched voltages, you may have an explosive fire.

Comment: Hi Winny, thanks for responding, i did more research on the battery. seems like each of the LiPolymer Cells/packs on it were connected in series and each cell has 4.400mAh. I was only using 1 of those four for testing since i cut off each of the packs from the original circuit the battery pack had, except for the HC85AY-1 that is on it, but i think it was a temperature fuse(?) not sure if it acts as a bms as well. But for the schematic its just the +,+ and -,- of the battery and the Tp4056 which is then connected to a type C charger, no loads etc, maybe it was fully drained that's why?

Comment: Did the voltage change during the 6-7 hours?

Comment: Yes it did, initially it was 3.64V, it went up to 3.80V but i stopped charging and let it rest for about 6hrs, then charged it again 2 hrs ago and now its 3.97V. noticed the BLUE LED turned on but the red light was also turned on on the TP4056 charger. the blue led turns on and it stays lit if i disconnect the battery and reconnect it. maybe its fully charged now?